# How to Make HTML Element Not Loop Inside Loop In WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

is this possible to make the post list like this in WordPress?

```
<div class="large-image">
  <img src="http://example.com">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
<div class="post-row"><!-- this is not a loop -->
  <div class="post-item"><!-- this is a loop -->
    <img src="http://example.com">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item"><!-- this is a loop -->
    <img src="http://example.com">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have try with this code below, but the `<div class="post-row">` always included in the loop.

```
<?php 

if ( have_posts() ) : $post_count = 0;
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    if ( $post_count = 0 ) { ?>

      <div class="large-image">
        <img src="http://example.com">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>

<?php } ?>

<div class"post-row">

<?php if ( $post_count > 0 ) { ?>

  <div class="post-item"><!-- this is a loop -->
    <img src="http://example.com">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>

<?php } ?>

</div><!-- /post-row -->

<?php
  endwhile
endif; 
?>
```

What I wanted is `<div class="post-row">` not looping.

I have try some answer in stackoverflow, but the `post-row` always looping.

Hope I get best answer.

Comment: _“but the <div class="post-row"> always included in the loop.”_ - because that’s where you put it … So put it outside then? What have you tried, and where exactly was the problem with it?

Comment: Btw., `if ( $post_count = 0 )` - that is an assignment and not a comparison.

Comment: Please read carefully. What I wanted is `<div class="post-row">` not looping. If the `<div class="post-row>` looping, it's a problem.

Comment: try this: https://3v4l.org/s4kra  (use code)

Comment: And what is the point of `if ( have_posts() ) : $post_count = 0;` supposed to be? `have_posts()` returning true means that there _are_ posts.

Comment: Also, `$post_count` will always be equal to 0 since you hard code that value to zero before the loop but never actually change it anywhere.

Comment: _“Please read carefully.”_ - don’t give me that, the problem here is not that we are not reading your question carefully enough, but that _you_ wrote code that _explicitly_ does the opposite of what you want. _You_ have placed this _inside_ the loop, and now you are complaining _that_ it gets output multiple times.

Comment: According to my understanding this is what OP want: if `<div class="post-row>` is looping then only one `<div class="post-row">` should wrap them. but if `<div class="post-row>` is not looping then each one of them needs to be wrapped inside `<div class="post-row">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must move the post-row div above the while loop, you just missed placed it that's all

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : $post_count = 0; 

if ( $post_count == 0 ) { ?>

      <div class="large-image">
        <img src="http://example.com">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>

<?php } ?>

<div class"post-row">

<?php

  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();


  if ( $post_count > 0 ) { ?>

  <div class="post-item"><!-- this is a loop -->
    <img src="http://example.com">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>

<?php } 

$post_count ++;

 endwhile; ?>

</div><!-- /post-row -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Not correct yet either, they want the `<div class="large-image">…</div>` element _before_ `<div class"post-row">`, but now you have placed it _inside_ of that.

Comment: okey that is static link you can move it up too let me edit my answer

Comment: Yes, I want `<div class="large-image">...</div>` element before `<div class="post-row">`. I realize what I want a bit complicated with WordPress development practice, but I hope I found answer by posting a question here.

Comment: Great! Work very well, dude. Thank you @ShakeelAhmad 